# Visual Studio resx generation format differences

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, resx

My team is having an odd problem where different peoples' Visual Studios will generate resx slightly differently, which can cause issues in merges.

Format 1:

```
<data name="ResourceName">
  <value xml:space="preserve">Value</value>
</data>
```

Format 2:

```
<data name="ResourceName" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Value</value>
</data>
```

Note position of the `xml:space="preserve"`.

I can't find what setting might govern this, or why it would be happening. Any ideas?

Comment: Are they all at the same service-pack level, with the same extensions?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they're all the same service pack level, SP1. Extensions vary a bit but nothing's jumping out of the lists as something that would affect this. It *could* be extensions... but I'm hoping it's not, because that would be a lot harder to pin down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use ReSharper?

If you use Visual Studio's `.resx` editor then the entry will be added as in format #2 but if you use ReSharper to add a resource, then the entry will be added as in format #1.

Comment: Huh. I think that might be it! I'm amazed I didn't think of that.